# Error connecting: io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to use socket.io to connect to the Nodejs server and Android client. I am getting the xhr poll error when trying to connect. I have seen such issues raised by other people, but with no solution. I have socket io 2.1.1 on node server and using 'io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3' in Android. My Android version is Oreo.

This is my Android client code:

```
package com.example.socketiodemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Manager;
import io.socket.client.Socket;
import io.socket.emitter.Emitter;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView display_text;
    private Socket mSocket;
    Manager mManager;
    private boolean fClientClosedConnection;
    private boolean fClientIsConnected;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        display_text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.display_text);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        fClientClosedConnection = false;
        fClientIsConnected = false;

        new MyAsyncTask(mSocket).execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        Socket mSocket;
        Manager mManager;
        MyAsyncTask(Socket socket) {
            mSocket = socket;
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Initiating the connection");


            try {

                mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.168.0.104:4444");
                mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, onConnect);
                mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, onDisconnect);
                mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
                mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, onTimeoutError);
                mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_ERROR, onError);
                mSocket.on("data", onNewMessage);
                mSocket.connect();
                while (!fClientClosedConnection) {
                    // Keep the thread active
                }
            }
            catch (URISyntaxException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "Finished the background Process");
            return "";
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            mSocket.close();
        }
    }

    private Emitter.Listener onConnect = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onConnect");
                    if(!fClientIsConnected) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Client is connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        fClientIsConnected = true;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };

    private Emitter.Listener onDisconnect = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.e(TAG, "diconnected");
                    fClientIsConnected = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Client is disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    };

    private Emitter.Listener onConnectError = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error connecting: " + args[0].toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Client connect error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    };

    private Emitter.Listener onTimeoutError = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Timeout Error ");
                }
            });
        }
    };

    private Emitter.Listener onError = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error ");
                }
            });
        }
    };

    private Emitter.Listener onNewMessage = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                    String message;
                    try {
                        message = data.getString("message");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                        return;
                    }

                    printMessage(message);
                    if (message.contentEquals("Bye"))
                    {
                        fClientClosedConnection = true;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };

    private void printMessage (String message)
    {
        display_text.setText(message);
    }
}
```

This is my nodejs server:

```
process.title = 'node-android';
var app = require('http').createServer()
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
app.listen(4444, onListenStart);

io.on('connection', onConnect);

function onListenStart()
{
    console.log("Server listening on port: " + SERVER_PORT);
}

function onConnect(client)
{
    console.log("client is connected");
    client.emit("data", { message: 'Hello'});
    client.on('event', onMessageReceived);
    client.on('disconnect', onDisconnect);
}

function onMessageReceived(data)
{
    console.log(data);
}

function onDisconnect()
{
    console.log("client is disconnected");
}
```

I get these logs:

```
05-20 21:48:56.404 28026-28026/com.example.socketiodemo E/MainActivity: Error connecting: io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error
05-20 21:48:57.921 28026-28026/com.example.socketiodemo E/MainActivity: Error connecting: io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error
```

Please help, as I have been stuck on this since 3 days.

Comment: did you solved this ?

Comment: anyone some solution for this?

Comment: have you get any solution . I am facing the same issue

Comment: @Abhishek have get any solution for this?

Comment: @DeepakRana I added SSL certificate which was required to authenticate with my server.

Comment: Use `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in AndroidManifest. See also https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java/issues/56#issuecomment-673520365 if you have certificate errors.

Answer (score 1):

> I have socket io 2.1.1 on node server and using 'io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3'

I had similar situation, changing library version to 1.0.0 helped.

Comment: Yes, using 'io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0' helped in connection stability and reconnection but if server is on HTTPS then it again fails to connect to server and above exception with SSLHandShake error.

Answer (score 0):

you must add this code in application tag in manifest like below,
It solved Error connecting: io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error
same issues

```
<Application . . android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"> . . . <Application/>
```